# How do I subclass a generic base class in a Groovy AST transformation?

Tags: generics, groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an abstract base class `Resource<A>` (written in Java) that contains some `A attributes`. I am writing an AST transformation to be applied to `FooAttributes` that will generate the wrapper class `FooResource extends Resource<FooAttributes>`, but I'm encountering an error about handling the `ClassNode`.

When I try to write this:

```
make(rc.fqcn).tap {
  superClass = makeWithoutCaching(Resource).tap { genericsTypes = [attr] as GenericsType[] }
}
```

I receive the compiler error

`transform used a generics containing ClassNode com.example.Resource<com.example.FooAttributes> for the super class com.example.FooResource directly. You are not supposed to do this. Please create a new ClassNode referring to the old ClassNode and use the new ClassNode instead of the old one. Otherwise the compiler will create wrong descriptors and a potential NullPointerException in TypeResolver in the OpenJDK. If this is not your own doing, please report this bug to the writer of the transform.`

(Presumably the "super class" is an error and meant to say "super class for".)

I have reviewed the APIs for `ClassNode` and `ClassHelper` and cannot find a way to "create a new node referring to the old node". I tried invoking `new ClassNode(String, int, ClassNode)`, but I received the same error.

What API calls should I use to create the "new `ClassNode`" for my generic `Resource<A>` class?

Comment: ClassNode r = make(Resource); ClassNode sc = r.getPlainNodeReference(); sc.setGenericsTypes(attr); // sc is used as superclass of FooResource; it redirects to r which carries the type parameter

Comment: You can also use GenericsUtils.makeClassSafe0(make(Resource), attr) which will get the plain reference and set the generics types

Comment: Or if attr is a ClassNode not a GenericsType, you can use GenericsUtils.makeClassSafeWithGenerics